# Django - Good database design practice: Should auxiliary fields be linked to the base user model or the employee model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, database-design, user-profile

My current database design uses the Django default **User model** for authentication (and authentication only). I also have an **Employee** model that has a one-to-one relationship with the **User** model and holds information such as the company they are at, the date they joined the company etc. I have another model called **Roles** - it contains information regarding various "roles" that an employee at that company might need to fulfil.

My question is: should the **Roles** model be linked by a foreign key to the **Employee** model or to the **User** model? There are several other models similar to the **Roles** model that need to be linked to either the **Employee** or the **User** but I am not sure which is best practice. In my mind it makes sense to link it to the **Employee** - this would make handling the event of a **User** moving companies far easier. But I have heard it is good practice to link everything to one central/base table - in this case the **User**.

Any advice would be much appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think you should link it with Employee cuz it's going to make the code easy to read for both beginners and experts. Most of the beginners don't know how to handle the User models so...